# How to convert a classic while loop to infinite scroll?

Tags: while-loop, infinite-scroll

I have a while loop which works great but it shows all results. How can I convert it to a infinite scroll?

This is my actual code;

```
$query=mysql_query("select * from images ORDER BY image_id DESC limit 10000"); 

        echo '<table>'; 

   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){ 
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    } 
       echo '</table>';
```

Comment: What do you mean by "convert it to an infinite scroll"?  Is this a PHP page?  How are loops related to "infinite scroll"?  If you're just asking "how do I implement an infinite scroll" then that's too broad for a Stack Overflow question.  There are plenty of examples and tutorials to be found on Google.

Comment: Yes this is a PHP page. There are all results are listed on actual page. I want to list them by infinite scroll. Tutorials to be found on Google explains how to make a new page with infinite scroll so they are so confusing for my page. Is there any way to do it easily?

Comment: "How do I implement an infinite scroll" is too broad.  Follow one or more tutorials on the subject.  If you get stuck on something specific, Stack Overflow will be happy to help.  But we don't offer entire tutorials here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer! For those who wants to do the same thing;

```html
$query=mysql_query("select * from images order by images_id desc limit 5");

  echo '<table>'; 

   while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>

<div class="boxLatest" id="'.$imageid.'">
 <div class="box">
  <div id="content">
       .
       .
       .
       .
</div>
 </div>
  </div>
   </td> 
  </tr>'; 
   } 
   
   echo '</table>'; 
echo '<div id="lastPostsLoader"></div>';
```

to **header.php**;

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  
  function lastPostFunc() 
  { 
   $('div#lastPostsLoader').html('<img src="bigloader.gif">');
   $.post("indexajax.php?lastid="+$(".boxLatest:last").attr("id"),
 
   function(data){
    if (data != "") {
    $(".boxLatest:last").after("<div class='newajax'>"+data+"</div>"); 
    $(".newajax").hide().fadeIn("fast");
    }
    $('div#lastPostsLoader').empty();
   });
  };  
  
  $(window).scroll(function(){
   if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
      lastPostFunc();
   }
  }); 
  
 });
</script>
```

to **indexajax.php**;

```html
$lastid=$_GET['lastid'];
 
 $lastquery=mysql_query("select * from resimler where resim_id < '$lastid' order by resim_id desc limit 5");

  echo '<table>'; 

   while($rowlast=mysql_fetch_assoc($lastquery)){ 
echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td>

    <div class="boxLatest" id="'.$imageid.'">
     <div class="box">
      <div id="content">
           .
           .
           .
           .
    </div>
     </div>
      </div>
       </td> 
      </tr>'; 
       } 
       
       echo '</table>';
```